# Is my choice of $\delta$ under the given bounds for M correct in this $\epsilon-\delta$ proof? Are the choices of < or = correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Prove that
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 9} \sqrt{x} = 3$$

---

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

**$\color{red}{\text{Choose} \ \delta = \min\{\epsilon(\sqrt{9-M} + 3), M\} \ \text{where} \ M \in (0,9)}$.**

Case 1: $\epsilon \le \frac{M}{\sqrt{9-M} + 3}$

Then $\delta = \epsilon(\sqrt{9-M} + 3)$

$$|\sqrt{x} - 3| = \frac{|x - 9|}{|\sqrt{x} + 3|}$$

$$= \frac{|x - 9|}{\sqrt{x} + 3}$$

$$< \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x} + 3}$$

$$= \frac{\epsilon(\sqrt{9-M} + 3)}{\sqrt{x} + 3}$$

$$< \frac{\epsilon(\sqrt{9-M} + 3)}{\sqrt{9-M} + 3} = \epsilon$$

because $|x-9| < \epsilon(\sqrt{9-M} + 3) \to |x-9| < M \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 3} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-M} + 3}$

Case 2: $\epsilon \ge \frac{M}{\sqrt{9-M} + 3}$

Then $\delta = M$

$$|\sqrt{x} - 3| = \frac{|x - 9|}{|\sqrt{x} + 3|}$$

$$ = \frac{|x - 9|}{\sqrt{x} + 3}$$

$$< \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x} + 3}$$

$$ = \frac{M}{\sqrt{x} + 3}$$

$$< \frac{M}{\sqrt{9-M} + 3} \le \epsilon$$

because $|x-9| < M \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 3} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-M} + 3}$

QED

Is that right?

Comment: As you (almost) wrote, we have $|\sqrt{x}-3|=\frac{|x-9|}{\sqrt{x}+3}\lt |x-9|$. So if we pick $\delta=\epsilon$, or to be cheaper, $\epsilon/3$, we are finished. But we don't want $x$ to dip below $0$, for square root reasons. So let $\delta=\min(\epsilon,9)$. (It is late, I do not have the time to write an analysis of what you wrote. )

Comment: @AndréNicolas Omg thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I do not understand the $M$ business. I should have written $\le 9$, to deal with $x=9$. And I really should have written $\le \frac{|x-9|}{3}$, but wrote $|x-9|$ to show that tight bounds are not needed.

Comment: Generally a proof needs to be reconsidered when the first few people responding cannot see what it tries to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I do not quite understand what you wrote. What I can tell you is that $\lim\limits_{x\to a^2}\sqrt x = a$, because we can choose $\delta = \epsilon$ and write $$\vert \sqrt x-a\vert =\frac{\vert x-a^2\vert}{\vert \sqrt x+a\vert}< \vert x-a^2\vert <\delta=\epsilon.$$ $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\textrm{This will  always work.}}$

---

**Edit:** As [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632873/is-my-choice-of-delta-under-the-given-bounds-for-m-correct-in-this-epsilon/1632905?noredirect=1#comment3341063_1632905) pointed out, this will of course only work if we know that $\vert \sqrt x+a\vert>1$. If this is not the case, then we have to resort to other (more cumbersome, for as far as I can see) methods.

Comment: No. This does not always work. It is perfectly possible that $\sqrt x+a$ has absolute value $<1$ in which case your first inequality is wrong. For example when $a=1/4$ and $x\to1/16$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are of course absolutely right. Than you for pointing it out. I made an edit.